# What's the best way to perform a differential between a list of directories?

Tags: perl, shell, unix

I am interested in looking at a list of directories and comparing the previous list with a current list of directories and setting up a script to do so. Maybe in perl or as a shell script.

Should I use something like diff? Programatically, what would be an ideal way to do this? For example let say I output the diff to an output file, if there is no diff then exit, if there is results, I want to see it.

Let's for example I have the following directories today:

```
/foo/bar/staging/abc
/foo/bar/staging/def
/foo/bar/staging/a1b2c3
```

Next day would look like this where a directory is either added, or renamed:

```
/foo/bar/staging/abc
/foo/bar/staging/def
/foo/bar/staging/ghi
/foo/bar/staging/a1b2c4
```

Comment: Just curious, what do you plan to do with this information? My unix tool senses are tingling.

Comment: just need to report on the differences as there is another process that adds, create directories and i need to know what has changed if there is changes. i would probably set it up to email me if such a change occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be better ways, but the way I typically do something like this is to run a find command in each directory root, and pipe the output to separate files.  You can then diff the files using the diff tool of your choice.  If you want to filter out certain directories or files, you can throw in some `grep` or `grep -v` commands in the pipeline, or you can experiment with options on the `find` command.

The other main option is to find a diff tool that offers directory/folder comparisons.  Most of the goods ones support this, but I like the command line method, because you get more control over what you're diffing.

```
cd /my/directory/one
find . -print | sort > /temp/one.txt

cd /my/directory/two
find . -print | sort > /temp/two.txt

diff /temp/one.txt /temp/two.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your input. Yes, I'm inclined to this as simple as possible and like the control. I do like the command line method too.

Comment: You might want to `find . -print | sort ...` as find doesn't guarantee any particular output order.

Comment: So if I do a diff and output it to a file and I get no results (0 bytes), then I'm not interested in seeing the output. But if there is results and its greater than 0 bytes then yes I want to see the output. How would I construct that logic? Can I do that as single line if?

Answer (score 0):

also check the [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) command. it allows you to monitor files in RT.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider the find command using the -newer switch.

The usage is:

```
find . -newer timefile.txt -print
```

The -newer switch makes find return a list of files that are created or updated after the specified file's modification time. In the example above, any file created or updated after timefile.txt would be returned. You'd have to create a timefile.txt file, most likely once per day. Some versions of find have variations of newer that compare against other time stamps for a file (last modified, last accessed, last created, etc.)

This technique would not report a file that was deleted, however. A daily diff of the file listings could report that.